# Laravel Forge:Struggling to deploy new changes to a specific website on a server Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, github, ssh, forge

I am currently very new to forge and need to work on existing websites deployed on forge. The issue I am having is not being able to deploy changes to one project while I have no problem pushing changes to the other existing websites running on the same server.
This is the error I got:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The other thing I noticed is that the latest changes to the repo were back in 2021...

I have seen a couple of solutions on here that I tried:

1- Added deployment key to the repo. It was already in use. My device's public ssh key is already added to the server and I don't have any trouble maintaining other older websites in the same server.

2- I tried sshing into the server and make sure my credentials were set up correctly. (git config ...)
3- set the remote url just in case it was the wrong one.

4-Made sure there were no ssh keys in an old developer account within the organization.

5-Used ssh-agent to generate a new key from the server and added it to my account.

6-Added deployment key to repo..It said the key is already in use.

Considering this is an issue with one repo I am starting to winder if the issue is beyond ssh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can try and set/export the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -Tv` in order to *see* which key is used during your deployment process.

Second, for testing, make sure to use a key created without passphrase (not encrypted), meaning ssh-agent should not be involved/needed at any point.

Comment: I set it like this: GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv"
However, it is not displaying anything at the moment. Did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: @erinam99 It depnd on your execution shell. On Linux/Mac, that would be `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv"`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and traced the issue. The deployment key was being used in an account I did not have access to that account so had to create a new deploy key and add it to the repo. Thank you!